# Git - merge base branch with current branch

Tags: git

Lets say I have a git branch (call it v1.1) that was created based on the branch named v1.0.  I make changes to files in the v1.1 branch and other engineers make changes in the v1.0 branch.  I have not yet finished making my changes to my branch (v1.1) and I want to include the changes that were made in v1.0 to my v1.1 branch.  How so I do this?  I can find plenty of documentation on how to merge my changes from my branch (v1.1) back into the v1.0 branch but nothing on how to refresh my a branch with updates from the base branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just switch to `v1.1`:

```
git checkout v1.1
```

then merge `v1.0` into it:

```
git merge v1.0
```

a related post: https://superuser.com/questions/224085/git-merge-master-into-a-branch

Comment: Yep...I figured it out right after I posted this.  I hate it when that happens.  It's good to know that the solution I came up with was the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This partly depends on what you need the branch for.  It looks like v1.1 in your case would be a branch that might be around for a while, so merging is probably fine.

But in other scenarios, such as if your branch is local only, and you are going to put it back in v1.0 when you are done with it, you might want to rebase instead.

```
git checkout v1.1
```

then rebase

```
git rebase v1.0
```

This will give you the changes in v1.0 without putting a merge commit into the history.

Both merge and rebase will do what you are looking for, you just have to chose the right one for what you are doing.